# How determine data type of points in geotiff DTM?

Tags: c#, dem, geotiff-tiff

I have some DTMs in geotiff files. I need to read them in C# and I've decided to use libtiff for that purpose. After some investigations, I've found that there are tiled tiffs, so I use ReadTile method to get raw points values. The strange thing for me, newbie to GIS technologies, is that one file seems to storage point elevation values as integers, but another one - as floats (4-byte, single precision). That's the result of comparison of values got by my code and  or  values from *.tif.aux.xml file.
So, my question is - is there any method to determine whether geotiff file stores values as intergers either floats? There is no answer for that in geotiff specs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [SampleFormat](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/help/sampleformat.aspx) and  BitsPerSample [tags](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/help/well-known-tags-and-their-value%28s%29-data-types.aspx) to determine the data type.